# layout design with scroll view and linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm an absolute beginner to android development and I'm developing a UI with scroll view and linear layout. Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:clipToPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/dashboardToolbar"
                android:layout_weight="0.04" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Manage Activities"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_weight="9.78"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_margin="21dp"
                android:fontFamily="cursive"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="470dp"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:background="@color/deeppurple"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="120dp">

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


            <!-- second row -->



            <!-- second row- -->


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting two linear layouts horizontally without any problem. What I want is making a third linear layout appear bottom of the first layout. Basically i'm developing dashboard UI for my app and i just want to make 2 columns and 5 rows linear layout matrix. I have commented area in my xml file called second row, If anyone can help me to provide xml code to that or idea to solve this I'm really grateful.

Comment: add screenshot of your deign

Comment: Sorry, i'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: I believe its better to use GridView instead of ScrollView in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this xml code to achieve your desire layout

***Code***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/dashboardToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".08"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="cursive"
                    android:text="Manage Activities"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".02" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".14">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".02" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".14">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".02" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".14">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".02" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".14">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".02" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".14">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Screen shot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to copy:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="470dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="120dp"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@color/deeppurple"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="120dp">

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

into your vertical LinearLayout.And it should work. But is the problem that it's not visible?

I see you have the first LinearLayout after the ScrollView as match_parent. It should be wrap_content to make the layout expand beyond the parent and be scrollable.

A good tip is to set different background colors to the layouts so you can see the size of each layout and check for mistakes in width/height.

**Edit:** I see that you have android:layout_height="470dp" in your horizontal LinearLayout and android:layout_height="120dp" in it's children. I don't know how it's supposed to look but that seems a bit strange, perhaps you should set the Layouts to different background colors just to make sure that this is the sizes you want.